# Multiline tooltip in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to display Multiline tooltip  in asp.net.

Comment: http://www.igtfy.com/?q=Multiline+tooltip+in+asp.net
Where are your concrete problems?

Comment: added multiline tooltip in asp:image in cs file.

Comment: downvoted since your question is not clear at all. Neither is your added comment. Try to describe your situation a bit more (in the question) and tell us what you have tried and what is going wrong / gives errors. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with Tipsy: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tipsy

Demo at: http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Comment: See answer below, this can be done easily in C#/vb.net.

Answer (score 7):

in c#:

```
control.ToolTip="First Line\nSecond Line";
```

in vb.net:

```
control.ToolTip="First Line"+vbCrLf+"Second Line"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) (along with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) with great success. I'd start there if you want multi-line tooltips or tooltips that contain images or any other HTML.